# Accessing a protected variable that is constantly changing

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am trying to access a protected variable through a derived class. It all works until the variable starts changing, as the variable that the derived class gets never changes.

Simplified parent class (stripped of unimportant stuff):

```
class Player
{
    protected Vector2 planeVec = new Vector2 (480/2, 600);

    public void Update(KeyboardState keyboard)
    {
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)
        {
            planeVec.Y += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the simplified derived class:

```
class Projectiles : Player
{
    List<Vector2> bullets = new List<Vector2>();

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))               
        {
            bullets.Add(planeVec);
        }
    }
}
```

The Vector2 values for bullets always registers a value of (480/2, 600) regardless of how much planeVec changes throughout runtime.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need to specify the tag along with question it is clearly mentioned in the tag field

Comment: @SujithKarivelil Oh, I'm quite new to StackOverflow, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: that's why i informed you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call `Update()` method for `Projectiles` class?

The following will not work, since base class `Update()` is not called in this case:

```
    Projectiles a = new Projectiles();
    a.Update();
    a.Update();
```

The following code will only call base class method:

```
    Projectiles a = new Projectiles();
    ((Player)a).Update();
    ((Player)a).Update();
```

I suggest to update `Projectiles.Update()` the following way:

```
public void Update()
{
    base.Update();
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))               
    {
        bullets.Add(planeVec);
    }
}
```

Adding `base.Update()` will first call base class method that will update the current state.

EDIT:

I'd also recommend to make base `Update()` method `virtual` and `override` it in the derived class. This will allow to avoid problems described in example above.

Comment: Adding base.Update() was exactly what was needed, fixed everything! Thanks a bunch!